# IOS: multilanguage app

Tags: ios, xcode, multilingual

I have a questions:

I should to do a multilanguage app and I would to know a method to manage graphics elements quickly.
A method is this:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSString *countryCode = [locale objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
if ([countryCode isEqualToString:@"US"]){
    //something to do
}
```

in this example I can set graphics elements in every viewcontroller, but there isn't a quickly solution to do all? at example in plsit file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think you can.
See this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/how-to-localize-an-iphone-app-tutorial
There is a paragraph where it says you can have different folders for different languages.

If that dos now work, at least you can have a singleton class where you check the "countryCode" just once, set it there and refer to it in your "if" statements.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XCode 4 just create a .strings file then in the file inspector you just hit the " +" button then you choose the language to add. In each file you will have (key, value) pairs.For example ( "firstViewTitle" = "First View"; ). the in the .m file just assign an NSLocalizedString to the title of the UI object. Befor running try to clean the target. Hope i made my self clear

Answer (score 0):

You can localize every item you want in an app.
E.g. once you have imported a resource (e.g. image) inside Xcode, just select the resource in the Navigator (left side) and then in the Assistant (right side) search for the "Localization" group and click the "+" button. The first time it will create a new folder and will move the resource to that folder (default is "English"). Later you can add as many languages as you want, for each language a dedicated folder will be created by Xcode and then you will be able to change your resource locally for each language. E.g. if you have an "image button" with a text you want to localize, once you have created all these folders you will be able to change the image file locally for each. Only requirement: keep the same name of course. Then iOS will be able to fetch the right file based on the current device/simulator localization setting.
Be aware that sometime if you change stuff the bundle is not compiled correctly and to avoid headaches while debugging the easiest solution is to clean the build and remove and re-install the app from the device/simulator.